# Position fixed; left works fine, right doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `span` called `$mySpan`.

Calling

```
$mySpan.css({
    position        : 'fixed',
    left            : '50%',
    top             : '15%',
    backgroundColor : 'red',
    'z-index'       : 1000
});
```

works just fine. However,

```
$mySpan.css({
    position        : 'fixed',
    right           : '50%',
    top             : '15%',
    backgroundColor : 'red',
    'z-index'       : 1000
});
```

doesn't show the span.

As you can see, it's probably not a `z-index` problem. I'm really confused because my code is quite complex and I haven't been able to build a simple example using jsFiddle. I have no clue where to start looking for what is going wrong.

Does anyone have a hint as to why the second approach is not working? How could I debug such a problem?

Comment: Is the missing `$` a typo, or?

Comment: Is the missing `$` in the second code snippet just a typo here, or do you have that in your actual code?

Comment: typo only... in the code it is correct

Comment: Have you tried debugging the CSS with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$mySpan.css({
    'position'        : 'fixed',
    'left'            : 'auto', /* <-- oftentimes, browsers screw up if 'left' is still set */
    'right'           : '50%',
    'top'             : '15%',
    'backgroundColor' : 'red',
    'z-index'         : 1000
});
```

Comment: @vzwick, what if the `left` attribute must have a value? If I let the `left: 'auto'`, my `div` would overflow its content to the left of the browser. Do you think this is a browser bug? (I tested this on Chrome)

Comment: @TrungDQ - a fiddle would be helpful ;)

Comment: Massively helpful.

Anyone know why this is the case?  Is it just poor browser implementation, or is there an actual logic as to why this would be required?  'Top' and 'Bottom' don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The unexpected result can be caused by a `margin-right` CSS property. If this property is set, remove it to fix your code.

Comment: I don't have any error message in the console, and I didn't make the error in the real code.

Comment: @Randomblue Updated answer with a possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

On the second example you may have missed the `$` at `$mySpan`?